# How to filter resource files based on wild card using only JAVA APIs

Tags: java, file, filter, resources, wildcard

I have several resource files located in META-INF folder in my spring project. I want to filter those files based on the file name using wild cards

Eg:
Files located in META-INF folder as follows

```
a-config.xml
b-config.xml
c-config.xml
```

What I want is to filter these files using the wild card `*-config.xml`

I already know that I can easily use spring `ResourcePatternResolver` for this.

I tried to use `java.io.FileFilter` but even for that I have to pass a RegEx to filter the file names.

eg:

```
FileFilter customFilter = new FileFilter() {
      @Override
      public boolean accept(File pathname) {
        if(pathname.getName().matches("(.*)config(.*)")) {
           return true;
        }
     return false;
      }
    };
```

Are there any other ways to do this without using any third party dependencies (Spring,Google Guava etc) and RegEX?  I want to use simple wild card characters to do the filtering. Your comments are highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please specify version of java that you are using ?

Comment: If filtering is not too complicated, you could go with String.startsWith or String.endsWith. But ... what is wrong with regular expressions?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose yes we can use String.startsWith or String.endsWith but we are searching for a better and more generic solution. Using RegEx is ok but I need to know there's no any other way to do this before finalize using RegEx. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I do not know about any other solution. A regular expression _is_ the generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

what you want is a less-expressive *pattern-matching* known as [**Glob**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob). one solution is to implement your own `globbing` using String class method (such as `startsWith`, `endsWith` ,...). but I think using `regex` is the best and general solution.